# Silverlight Data Context, datagrid

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, datagrid

I have datagrid view where is data from sql tables also every row has button which show childwindow.  In this childwindow are few texboxs, comboboxs and datapickers and I need fill this controls data from my datagrid. I use method to fill datagrid below.

```
    public ObservableCollection<MyClass> ReadUpdate(int id_update)
{
ObservableCollection<MyClass> result = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
string nwConn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlDataReader dr;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(nwConn);
try
{
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "Insert_Update";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_update", id_update);
conn.Open();
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
MyClass lin = new MyClass();

lin.id = dr.GetInt32(1);
if (!dr.IsDBNull(2)) lin.other = dr.GetString(2);
if (!dr.IsDBNull(3)) lin.barkod = dr.GetString(3);
if (!dr.IsDBNull(4)) lin.pw = dr.GetInt32(4);

result.Add(lin);
}
dr.Close();
return result;

}
catch (SqlException e)
{
MyClass lin = new MyClass();
lin.other = e.Message;

result.Add(lin);
return result;

}
finally
{
conn.Close();

};
}
```

My class:

```
public class PIS
{
public int ID { get; set; } 
public int PW { get; set;}
public string other { get; set;}
public string barkod { get; set;}
 }
```

My datagrid and method that insert data ther (works ok)

```
private PIS pis_update;

 public Home() 
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            webService = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
            webService.ReadPismaCompleted += WebService_ReadPismaCompleted;
            webService.ReadPismaAsync(0);

        }

        private void WebService_ReadPismaCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.ReadPismaCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
                if (e.Result != null)
                {             
                dataGridPisma.ItemsSource = e.Result;  

            }
        }
```

My button:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             pismo_update = (PIS)((Button)sender).DataContext;  

            ChildWindow_Update childWindow_update = new ChildWindow_Update();


            childWindow_update.DataContext = ((PIS)((Button)sender).DataContext).Id_Pis;

            childWindow_update.Closed += ChildWindow_Update_Closed;
            childWindow_update.Show();

        }

        private void ChildWindow_Update_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (((ChildWindow_Update)sender).DialogResult.Value)
            {
                webService.ReadPismaAsync(0);
            }
        }
```

My xaml:

```html
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1_other" Text="{Binding Path= other}"/>

<TextBox x:Name="textBox2_barkod" Text="{Binding Path= barkod}"/>

 <ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxPW" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,117,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="366"   
            SelectedItem="{Binding ReadComboboxPW}"   DisplayMemberPath="PW"  SelectedValuePath="IDPW"  />
```

I try after button click send datacontext my class and insert into controls in childwindow, it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Dude, I would suggest you work on your english, it's even worse than mine, which could explain why people are not rushing here to help you.

Anyway, I'm not sure I totally understand your goal, still this line:

```
childWindow_update.DataContext = ((PIS)((Button)sender).DataContext).Id_Pis;
```

Is quite odd. It clearly states you want as dataContext only the Id of your PIS object. Is it really what you need?

Something more conventional is to have a full object as DataContext (like a full PIS object).

Hope it helps, otherwise try to be more explicit to explain your problem.

Comment: You're right, I need datacontext of entire row, but that does not solve my problem, because I do not know what is the next step.